# (Gravity form / Wordpress) Creating a floating field within a form

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I have an existing form with some main and conditional fields.
I want the conditional fields to show as a floating pop-up beside the main fields (instead of having that conditional fields showing within the page/form itself), but there seems to have no native way of doing it, nor existing add-on. Any input on how I could do it?
Thanks!

Comment: Might want to try posting here for more answers: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: [wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com) doesn't accept questions about plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help: https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-nested-forms/

You can make the nested forms show up with conditional logic in your setup. The nested forms appear in a pop-up window.